# Using an explicit interface for Lapack in Fortran: linking fails looking for a module file

Tags: external, lapack, blas, explicit-interface

### Problem

After adding an external interface for Lapack, the code fails during linking with the message

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___msolutionsvd_MOD_dgesvd", referenced from:
      ___msolutionsvd_MOD_svd_pseudoinverse_solve_sub in m-solution-svd.o
```

It seems that the linker is looking for a `DGESVD.mod` file which is not included with my `openblas` installation.

### Code

#### This works

The module `module mSolutionSVD` used the declaration

`external DGESVD`

to point to the BLAS routine and `contains` `subroutine svd_pseudoinverse_solve_sub`
which calls `DGESVD`.

#### This fails

The declaration was replaced with the explicit interface

```
    interface lapack
        module subroutine DGESVD ( JOBU, JOBVT, M, N, A, LDA, S, U, LDU, VT, LDVT, WORK, LWORK, INFO )
            character ( kind = kindA, len = 1 ), intent ( in )    :: JOBU, JOBVT
            integer ( kind = ip ),               intent ( in )    :: M, N, LDA, LDU, LWORK
            integer ( kind = ip ),               intent ( out )   :: INFO
            real ( kind = rp ),                  intent ( out )   :: S ( : ), U ( : , : ), VT ( : , : ), WORK ( : )
            real ( kind = rp ),                  intent ( inout ) :: A ( : , : )
        end subroutine DGESVD
    end interface lapack
```

#### Background

The kind statements are sourced from a routine with these statements:

```
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only : INT8, REAL64
integer, parameter :: kindA = kind ( 'A' ) 
integer, parameter :: rp = selected_real_kind ( REAL64 )
integer, parameter :: ip = selected_int_kind  ( INT64 )
```

### Question

Can we use an external interface for Lapack without having to recompile Lapack?

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems with your code, two of them not related to your question.

First, the definition of the data types should be

```
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only : INT64, REAL64
integer, parameter :: kindA = kind ( 'A' ) 
integer, parameter :: rp = REAL64
integer, parameter :: ip = INT64
```

This is because the predefined constants `INT64` and `REAL64` already represent the ranks, while the auxiliary functions `selected_*_kind` expect to be given the number of valid decimal places.

Second, your interface does not specify the parameter `LDVT`.

Third, and most importantly, you declare `DGESVD` as a `module subroutine`, by which you say that the subroutine is located in the present module. But it is not. Lapack subroutines are not in any modules. So, you need to omit the `module` keyword from your interface definition.

Note: If the data types `kindA`, `rp` and `ip` are defined in the same module, then after removing the `module` keyword from the interface declaration you will also need to add the line

```
import kindA, ip, rp
```

just below the prototype line `subroutine DGESVD (...`